# Why does purrr::map not support quasiquotation?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, rlang

I'm curious why the `purrr::map_*` function family, despite being a part of `tidyverse`, does not support quasiquotation by splice-unquoting its `dots` prior to evaluation of the mapped function?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

set.seed(1)
dots <- quos(digits = 2L)

# this obviously won't work
purrr::map_chr(rnorm(5L), 
               ~ format(.x, !!!dots))
#> Error in !dots: invalid argument type

# I'm confused why this does not work
purrr::map_chr(rnorm(5L), 
               ~ format(.x, ...), 
               !!!dots)
#> Error in !dots: invalid argument type

# Finally, this works
eval_tidy(expr(
  purrr::map_chr(rnorm(5L), 
                 ~ format(.x, ...), 
                 !!!dots)
))
#> [1] "1.5"   "0.39"  "-0.62" "-2.2"  "1.1"
```

Created on 2019-01-31 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is `format` does not support tidy dots -- you can use `exec` to force a function to be able to use them:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

set.seed(1)

nums <- rnorm(5L) #for some reason couldn't replicate your numbers
nums
#[1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078

dots <- exprs(digits = 2L)

map_chr(nums, ~exec(format, .x, !!!dots))
#[1] "-0.63" "0.18"  "-0.84" "1.6"   "0.33"
```

You also need to use `exprs` not `quos` to capture the additional function arguments for this to work (not entirely sure why `quos` doesn't work here though, to be honest).

Comment: That's true, that's why the error is returned. However my concern is the reason why the arguments are not unspliced before calling the function (eg. in the way `rlang::call2` does).